# Feeding array as data matrix to QgsRasterLayer

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-3

I am writing a PyQGIS processing script that takes a raster layer as an input, gets its data matrix as an array, makes some modifications over the data, and should produce a new raster layer as an output (with all the modifications made over the data matrix).

I'm able to get the data matrix using the `block` method. This is the relevant code:

```
layer = QgsRasterLayer(filepath, 'layer', 'gdal')  #QgsRasterLayer object
band = 1
extent = layer.extent()
cols = layer.width()
rows = layer.height()
provider = layer.dataProvider()
matrix = provider.block(band, extent, cols, rows)
```

After that, I do some modifications over the matrix object.

I would like to know how to assign or store the modified matrix data into a QgsRasterLayer object, so I can export it as an output of my processing script.

How can I do this?

I know there is a way to store that matrix into a raster band using GDAL's `WriteArray` method, however, I would like to store the data into a QgsRasterLayer object to take advantage of the QGIS GUI infrastructure.